# Bert prediction shape not equal to num_samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I have a text classification that I am trying to do using BERT. Below is the code I am using. The model training code(below) works fine but I am facing issue with the prediction part

```
from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf

# recommended learning rate for Adam 5e-5, 3e-5, 2e-5
learning_rate = 5e-5
nlabels = 26

# we will do just 1 epoch for illustration, though multiple epochs might be better as long as we will not overfit the model
number_of_epochs = 1


# model initialization
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=nlabels,
                                                      output_attentions=False,
                                                      output_hidden_states=False)

# optimizer Adam
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=1e-08)

# we do not have one-hot vectors, we can use sparce categorical cross entropy and accuracy
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])

bert_history = model.fit(ds_tr_encoded, epochs=number_of_epochs)
```

I am getting the output using the following

```
preds = model.predict(ds_te_encoded)
pred_labels_idx = np.argmax(preds['logits'], axis=1)
```

The issue I am facing is that the shape of `pred_labels_idx` is not the same as `ds_te_encoded`

```
len(pred_labels_idx) #426820
tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds_te_encoded) #<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=21341>
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: what is the shape of `preds['logits']`?

Comment: @AloneTogether the shape is `(426820, 26)`

Comment: And what is the shape and type of `ds_te_encoded `

Comment: Its in the post itself. I ran `tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds_te_encoded)` which returns `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=21341>` ie 21341

Comment: type is `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ds_te_encoded` is of type `tf.data.Dataset` and you call `cardinality(...)`, the cardinality in your case is simply the rounded number of **batches** and *not* the number of samples. So I am assuming you are using a batch size of 20, because `426820/20 = 21341`. That is probably what is causing the confusion.

Comment: okay makes sense, but why is shape of `preds` 426820? How do I get predictions that are the shape of my data?

Comment: That is how `model.predict` works --> "returns Numpy array(s) of predictions.". It does not return batches of predictions and it also does not return a `tf.data.Dataset`. You can reshape the output if you want. Does that make sense? @ClockSlave

Comment: makes sense. I was able to figure out how to get the predictions. Thanks for pointing me out in the right directions